# The operation failed to complete because the Disk Management console view is not up-to-date(add mirror win server 2012)

Tags: windows-server-2012, mirroring

I have a problem when add mirror in disk management window server 2012

The problem is:

> The operation failed to complete because the Disk Management console
> view is not up-to-date. Refresh the view by using the refresh task. If
> the problem persists close the Disk Management console, then restart
> Disk Management or restart the computer

I already reinstall disk and restart server but problem still persist It seems problem is by partition, not by disk because of i do a test by created a small other partition of first disk and mirroring to second and result is OK

Below link is output of `List volume` command, please refer it for more details
https://ibb.co/K63n9kq

@Ramhound
Thank you for your support
I already remove disk that unsigned drive as your suggestion but i still can not add mirror. Please refer to below link for details of error

- List of volume: https://ibb.co/FbrN7NC
- Error when add mirror: https://ibb.co/qjCpNqs

If someone went through this problem, please give me your advice

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I already reinstalled the disk and restart the server but the problem
> still persist It seems the problem is by a partition, not by disk
> because I do a test by created a small other partition of the first
> disk and mirroring to the second and the result is OK

You will have to run `diskpart` in an elevated command prompt then run the following commands.  This will assign the 1.8 TB partition that doesn't have a drive letter, a drive letter, based on my research the error is likely caused by the partition not having a driver letter.

Normally, a partition can happily exist without a drive letter assigned to it, but I suspect your partition layout is partially to blame.

1. Backup all important files
2. Select volume 4
3. Assign letter=G
4. Reboot

Comment: If assigning a drive letter does not work, you can remove the drive letter, using the appropriate command.  If you are prompted to **format** the partition, which might happen depending on the state of the file system of the partition, you shouldn't do that (unless you want to lose the data on the partition itself).